# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, fatal-error

I am trying to run a project but I am getting the below error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in E:\wampserver\www\NeoBook\application\controllers\usercp.php on line 2
```

I checked all the solutions in SO but none worked for me. I am a newbie to CodeIgniter, can anybody help me out in fixing this issue?

Please let me know if you need anymore information about this question.

Also while using

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//Page is responding as `No direct script access allowed`


    class Usercp extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            include_once('member/library/Am/Lite.php'); 
            $this->is_logged_in();
            $this->load->model('model_facebook');
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->library('Layouts');
            $this->load->model('model_user');
        }

    }
```

This is the code. Wherever class CI_Controller been used is not working.

Comment: Which version of CI you are using?

Comment: Also can you please give the code for your controller.

Comment: So show us what's on line 2 of that file.

Comment: @mlakhara - Updated, please check!

Comment: @Sparky - Updated, please check!

Comment: @Dr.Dan - How can I check my version details? I tried using `echo CI_VERSION;` but it gave me an output as `CI_VERSION` only.

Comment: what is the address you are trying to run the project with?

Comment: It seems like every error is trying to tell you something relevant and you just ignore it.

Comment: I'm a CI newbie too but I carefully read the documentation and did the included tutorials.  It will really make all the difference.

Comment: did you test the CI support include_once(), if it is check the Library path you given and path specified in the 'config'

Comment: Your `<?php`  tags should open at the start of the document...

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP tag inside a PHP tag use this (Removed '

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//Page is responding as `No direct script access allowed`
    class Usercp extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            include_once('member/library/Am/Lite.php'); 
            $this->is_logged_in();
            /// More of your code.
            $this->load->library('Layouts');
            $this->load->model('model_user');
        }

    }
```

Comment: No, I didn't inherit PHP tag and I posted my question separately but someone edited it and mixed the code.